# Why didn't the rebels use this weapon more often?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In The Force Unleashed II Starkiller activates a huge gun (Fusion Accelerator Cannon) to utterly annihilate a Star Destroyer. My question is, why didn't the rebels use more of these? I mean, perhaps they were expensive, but it can destroy a Star Destroyer in one hit!

**Possible answers I've considered:**

- The gun was a prototype, and the rebels forgot how to make it after Starkiller smashed it into the planet's shield

Or

- The gun was only that powerful because Starkiller powered it up with Force Lightning

Is it one of these?

Comment: I thought you were going to ask about Starkiller himself, given he'd utterly annihilated a Star Destroyer by himself.

Comment: Because it was a retcon created at the tail end of the legends canon.

Comment: Because it requires too much energy, that's why they built a smaller one on the land of Hoth with it's own gigantic generator and shield.

Comment: @CptEric find evidence for that, and make it an answer, and I'll accept it

Comment: just an assumption based on currently existing similar "canon" (no pun intended) weaponry. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6X3Hv1YLhG8

Answer (score 1):

In-universe, the cannon was a prototype, difficult to use, prone to malfunctions blah, blah, blah ... :D

Out-of-universe, as you mentioned yourself, such a weapon would disturb the balance in whole SW universe. Therefore it was left-out from canon, as is whole Starkiller saga. Games itself were not bad, but introduced whole lot of new concepts that run contrary to main intention.