# Star Wars Technical Question

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

If anyone is an expert in physics in fiction, this question would be for you. I am in Star Wars versus debate and specifically debating the function of a cannon which was activated by Starkiller in Force Unleashed II. A video of the cannon can be found herein,

The question is whether the cannon was activated via Starkiller's own power or if he simply provided the starting energy which was "boosted" to achieve the result. Is the second option mathematically possible? I would happily provide more details about the feat in later responses.

Comment: Good question if you leave out the 'mathematically possible' part. We unfortunately cannot discuss ['real world sciences'](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7364/21267) on this site.

Comment: I wish this had been about something from legends, so we could debate whether the cannon is canon.

Comment: Force Unleashed is legends.

Comment: Related, not dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160446/why-didnt-the-rebels-use-this-weapon-more-often